# Как вытащить из БД данные за месяц?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из БД SQLite вытащить данные за месяц. В таблице `student` есть столбик `Date`, как вытащить данные именно за промежуток времени?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE Date BETWEEN '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-29'
```